# How set cookie sent from server to a client on a different port

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, port, webpack-dev-server

I have a backend server (powered by Rails), whose APIs are used by a HTML5 frontend that runs on a Node simple development server.

Both are on the same host: my machine.

When I login from the frontend to the backend, rails sent me the session cookie. I can see it in the response headers, the problem is that browsers do not save it.

Policies are right, If I serve the same frontend directly from the rails app cookies are set right.

The only difference I can see is that when the frontend run on Node server, It runs on the port `8080` and rails is on the port `3000`. I knew that cookies are not supposed to be port specific, so I am missing what is happening here.

Any thoughts? solutions?

(I need to be able to keep the setup this way, so to have the frontend served from Node and the backend on rails on different ports)

Comment: Use a JWT token based authentication system instead of cookies/sessions. Such as [Knock](https://github.com/nsarno/knock) or [devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth).

Comment: JWT is entirely orthogonal to the question. Yes, a JWT can be sent via the `Authorization` header rather than through a cookie, but so can the OP's current authentication token. Cookies are a convenience.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're correct that cookies are port agnostic, and that the browser will send the same cookies to myapp.local:3000 as myapp.local:8080--*except not through XMLHttpRequest* (XHR, a.k.a., AJAX) when doing a cross-site request (CORS).

**Solution:** The request can be told to include cookies and auth headers by setting `withCredentials` to `true` on any XMLHttpRequest object. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials

Or if using the Fetch API, set the option `credentials: 'include'`. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

**Alternative:** since you tagged webpack-dev-server in your question, you might be interested in proxying requests to your Rails API through the webpack-dev-server to avoid any CORS issues in the first place. This is done in your weback.config:

```
proxy: {
  '/some/path': {
    target: 'https://other-server.example.com',
    secure: false
  }
}
```

See: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy

Comment: This is why I love this place, great answer that solved my problem and even a better alternative! thanks man!